# Clear not used properties from auto-complete in Neo4J console

Tags: neo4j

Is there a way to update Neo4J console to stop show properties that not in use any more?
I cleaned all my nodes from some property, and it keep showing it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Neo4j browser just shows the returned values from `CALL db.propertyKeys()`. Currently, this procedure is returning unused properties too. There is an open issue on Neo4j Github Repository (as you can see [here](https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j/issues/10941)) related to it that can fix this behavior.